# How can I slice a timeseries dataframe in Pandas based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe, subset

I need to take slices of a timeseries dataframe based on these 2 conditions:

1. The date of start of every slice is found in a second dataframe index.
2. The hour of start of every slice and the length of the slices are parameters of your function.

Let's see it with an example

df1 - This is where we take the slices from

```
                     A  B      
DateTime                                               
2011-01-02 00:00:00  1  2  
2011-01-02 04:00:00  2  4    
2011-01-02 08:00:00  3  5      
2011-01-02 12:00:00  2  6   
2011-01-02 16:00:00  5  6
2011-01-02 20:00:00  2  1
2011-01-03 00:00:00  5  2 
2011-01-03 04:00:00  3  3
2011-01-03 08:00:00  2  2
2011-01-03 12:00:00  0  4
2011-01-03 16:00:00  5  4
2011-01-03 20:00:00  1  1

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-02 00:00:00, ..., 2011-01-03 20:00:00]
Length: 12, Freq: 240T, Timezone: None
```

df2 - This is where the date part of the start of the slices is located.

```
                     N  
DateTime                                                                  
2011-01-10 00:00:00  1  
2011-03-10 00:00:00  2

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-02, ..., 2011-01-03]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Say we wanted to slice `df1['A']` in intervals of `length=4`, with start of each interval at time `'04:00:00'`, on each of the dates of `df2`....The desired output example would be:

```
func(df1['A'], df2, lenght=4, start_time='04:00')

                     A    
DateTime                                                 
2011-01-02 04:00:00  2   
2011-01-02 08:00:00  3    
2011-01-02 12:00:00  2   
2011-01-02 16:00:00  5     
2011-01-03 04:00:00  3   
2011-01-03 08:00:00  2   
2011-01-03 12:00:00  0   
2011-01-03 16:00:00  5
```

Things to consider:

- The Freq of df1 doesn't need to always be '240T'
- The dates in df2 don't need to be consecutive, I just set it like this for simplicity of the example.
- Not all the dates on df1 are on df2, but all the dates of df2 are in df1
- The column N in df2 can be ignored
- df2 freq attribute is always going to be 'None'
- The length of the slices can be anything, so they can be multi-day.

What have I tried:

With some help here I tried this approach, but only worked well when both df's freq was 'None'.

```
def next_n_asof(x, t, n):
    i = np.argmax(df1.index >= t)
    return x[i:i + n]

pd.concat(next_n_asof(df1.A, t, 4)
               for t in df2.index)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very small change in `next_n_asof` produces the desired result. If instead of

```
i = np.argmax(df1.index >= t)
```

you use

```
i = np.argmax(df1.index > t)
```

then your code produces

```
2011-01-02 04:00:00    2
2011-01-02 08:00:00    3
2011-01-02 12:00:00    2
2011-01-02 16:00:00    5
2011-01-03 04:00:00    3
2011-01-03 08:00:00    2
2011-01-03 12:00:00    0
2011-01-03 16:00:00    5
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem because that seems too easy.

---

Nevertheless, here is an alternative which may be faster:
Notice that this code uses a `for-loop` with `len(df2.index)` iterations

```
pd.concat(next_n_asof(df1.A, t, 4) for t in df2.index)
```

You could instead use

```
start = df1.index.get_indexer_for(df2.index)
```

to find the indices where the Timestamps in `df2.index` equal the Timestamp in `df1.index`. For example,

```
In [93]: df1.index.get_indexer_for(df2.index)
Out[93]: array([0, 6])
```

Using the DatetimeIndex's `get_indexer_for` method is faster than using this list comprehension:

```
In [101]: [np.argmax(df1.index >= t) for t in df2.index]
Out[101]: [0, 6]

In [103]: %timeit [np.argmax(df1.index >= t) for t in df2.index]
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.5 µs per loop

In [104]: %timeit df1.index.get_indexer_for(df2.index)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.5 µs per loop
```

From there it is not hard to create a boolean mask of all the desired indices for rows in `df1` you wish to select:

```
mask = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='bool')
for i in range(length):
    mask[start+i] = True
```

You can then select the desired rows from `df1` using

```
df1.loc[mask]
```

rather than creating (possibly) lots of smaller DataFrames and then
concatenating them with `pd.concat` which is slower if there are lots of sub-DataFrames.

So this alternative method trades a `for-loop` with `len(df2.index)` iterations
for a `for-loop` with `n=4` iterations (in the example problem you posed). If `df2` is
large but `n` is small, this alternative method should be faster.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 0, 5, 1],
                    'B': [2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1]},
                   index=pd.date_range('2011-1-2', '2011-01-03 20:00', freq='240T'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'N': 1}, index=pd.date_range('2011-1-2', '2011-01-03'))

def next_n_asof(x, t, n):
    i = np.argmax(df1.index > t)
    return x[i:i + n]

print(pd.concat(next_n_asof(df1.A, t, 4)
               for t in df2.index))


def func(df, index, length):
    start = df.index.get_indexer_for(index)
    mask = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='bool')
    for i in range(length):
        mask[start+i] = True
    return df.loc[mask]

index = df2.index + pd.DateOffset(hour=4)
print(func(df1['A'], index, length=4))
```

yields

```
2011-01-02 04:00:00    2
2011-01-02 08:00:00    3
2011-01-02 12:00:00    2
2011-01-02 16:00:00    5
2011-01-03 04:00:00    3
2011-01-03 08:00:00    2
2011-01-03 12:00:00    0
2011-01-03 16:00:00    5
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The problem is the assumption of freq = 'D' in df2. As I pointed out in the considerations, the dates will not be continuous, so df2 freq would be ='None', unless there's a way to change that.

Comment: Regardless, I would try your solution with the real data, and let you know. It'll take me a 20-40 mins.

Comment: I don't think the code depends on the `freq`. I just used that to set up the example.

Comment: This is really bizarre. If I just do copy paste of your answer (for the second method) I get 'TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable'. And with the first method, it works fine for the dummy example, but in real life, it concats slices for all the dates in the real df1....this is frustrating.

Comment: Okay, how about we start by you posting the full traceback error message. This will, among other things, show the line which is raising the TypeError. It will also help if you can work out a small example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-107-3048166b050b>", line 9, in <module>
    print(func(df1['A'], index, length=4))

  File "<ipython-input-107-3048166b050b>", line 4, in func
    for i in range(length):

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your code you've defined a variable named `range` which is a `Series` object. This shadows [the Python builtin function of the same name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). This is a Pitfall; never do this! Find the `range` variable and rename it.

Comment: So the real data is the same as the dummy data we use for the example....just longer. df1 is 27625 rows and df2 is 52 rows. Also df1 is in '120T'. Both df1 and df2 have a lot more columns. The length I used was 36. Other than that is the same as the dummy